# Issue with django json response

Tags: python, django, jsonresponse

I have issue with json response.  `messages.values()` gives me `user_id` instead of username. How to get username?

Here is my code:

```
class LivechatMessage(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)


def getMessages(request):
    messages =LivechatMessage.objects.all()
    return JsonResponse({"messages":list(messages.values())})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this to access related attributes

```
def getMessages(request):
    messages =LivechatMessage.objects.all()
    return JsonResponse({"messages":list(messages.values('user__username','user__id'))})
```